# Implement Packet capturing for HTTPS website

Tags: java, sockets, curl, socket.io, serversocket

I have implemented a packet capturing tool using the java IO API. And I have set the port to 8081. The issue is that when i try to access a https website such response does not get captured in my programm. I am developing a sample appliaction to demonstrate traffic shaping. As per my knowlege port 8080 and 8081 does not support https requests but when I set the port as below snippet the code throws errors.

ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

```
    int port = 8081;    //default

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Started on: " + port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

The below snipet is where i try to capture the response packets and get the count of packets that is been read. HTTP does get counted but HTTPS request doesn't

```
 URL oracle = new URL(urlToCall);
            URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
            is = yc.getInputStream();


            final byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // 1kb

            int index = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE); // insert first packet
            int i = 0;
            while (index != -1)
```

Any idea how to get through this?
Thank you

Comment: Add the errors that are thrown, including full stack trace.

Comment: "*port 8080 and 8081 does not support https requests*" This is not correct. Like with any other application layer protocol you can also run `https` via any IP port.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real problem here is that you are going about packet capture the wrong way.  (Or maybe you means something different to what everyone else means by packet capture.)

In a real packet capture application, the aim is for you application to capture packets going between an existing client and server.

But your program is creating / binding a `ServerSocket` ... presumably to allow it yo accept connections.  That means that your program will be a server / service.  It won't intercept traffic between clients and other servers.

The normal way to implement packet capture in java is to use the [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/) library.

---

If `new ServerSocket(port)` is failing, it is most likely that some other application has already bound to that port.  Most likely it is the server you are attempting to "snoop" on.  If you printed the stack trace, I expect it would confirm this.